# Why can Python's yield statement not be called in a function and also in another function that it calls and why no error reported when attempted?

Tags: python, yield

I'm new to Python and I am finding the `yield` statement quite useful.  However, something surprised me.  Putting multiple `yield` statements in a function will result in each one being seen in a `for var in fn()` loop.  However, if I execute another function from the initial function that uses the `yield` statement, that function is not executed.  I had just taken the naive approach and just thought it would work.

E.g.

```py
def fn2():
    print("blah")
    yield "you"
    
def fn():
    yield "hi"
    fn2()
    yield "there"
    
for a in fn():
    print('{}'.format(a))
```

If I were to comment out `yield "you"`, my output would be:

```
hi
there
```

If not, it would be:

```
hi
blah
there
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/xnP4qT3nE)</kbd>

That there wasn't any warning or error of any sort and it just shrugged and continued to execute was even more surprising than it not working.

What's going on here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Functions with `yield` are *generators*. They always produce an iterable, even if there is only a single `yield` statement in them.

In order to get the value(s) the function produces, you must iterate.

You could use `for v in fn2: yield v`, but Python also has a convenience statement: `yield from`

```
def fn2():
    print("blah")
    yield "you"
    
def fn():
    yield "hi"
    yield from fn2()
    yield "there"
    
for a in fn():
    print('{}'.format(a))
```

Python's generators are evaluated lazily.  Creating one (in this case *"calling `fn2`"*) does not start the iteration. That's why it seems that `fn2` isn't even called. It is called.

Imagine its return value as a bookmark right before the first line of the function body of `fn2`. Once you actually start iterating, the "bookmark" will advance to the first `yield` statement, and so on, until the function ends.